# Uniswap - TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortsBefore' of undefined

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

We're building an ERC20 token and we're planning to deploy it on Uniswap.

Currently, we want to get the conversion rate on Uniswap but we're getting this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortsBefore' of undefined
```

Here's the code:

```
require('rootpath')();

const {ChainId, Token, WETH, Fetcher, Route, Pair} = require('@uniswap/sdk');
const {Config} = require('config');
const Web3 = require('web3');

module.exports = class UniswapManager {

    // Docs: https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/javascript-SDK/pricing/
    static async getPrice() {
        const network = ChainId.RINKEBY;

        const HelloWorldContract = Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(Config.Contract.token()); 
        const HWD = new Token(network, HelloWorldContract, 18);   
        const pair = new Pair(HWD, WETH[network]); > Error here
        const route = new Route([pair], WETH[network]); 

        // Logging only
        return  'HWD/ETH: ' + route.midPrice.toSignificant(6) + '\n' +
                'ETH/HWD: ' + route.midPrice.invert().toSignificant(6);
    }

}
```

UNI to ETH is working perfectly but not our ERC20 token.

```
const UniswapContract= Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress('0x5592ec0cfb4dbc12d3ab100b257153436a1f0fea'); // Rinkeby
const Uniswap = new Token(network, UniswapContract, 18);    
const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(Uniswap, WETH[network])
const route = new Route([pair], WETH[network]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your token like

```
const WETH = new Token(
  router.chainId,
  '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
  18,
  'WETH',
  'Wrapped Ether'
);
```

chainID, address, decimals, symbol, name

Answer (score -2):

it's because you're not defining the pair correctly

Comment: If the OP didn't define it correctly, please show them how they can do it correctly.